# How to chown a directory so that new files are also owned? (web server)

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm operating my own development web server and have run into a bit of a squeeze.

I have my server with disallowed root login and my own account, let's call it bob.

I have apache2 virtual host set to make the website at `/var/www/site/public_html/`

How can I chown `site/public_html` to bob so that anything bob makes there belongs to him, and so that he can delete files there as well?

Thanks in advance

(running Ubuntu Server 13.04)

I've tried: `chown -R bob:bob *` - This worked (allowed me to delete files that I was previously unable to, however I want to be sure that this will stick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any files made by Bob (on a filesystem that allows ownership of files, most do), will be owned by bob, and because he owns them he will be able to delete them.

Of-course, if root makes files which bob can not write, then bob can't delete them.

Long story short, the changes will stick - provided bob makes the files.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that information. Learn something new every day, as they say!